# Access-Control-Allow-Credentials is added twice in Spring application

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, cors

For some reason I'm getting the `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` header twice on the `j_spring_security_check` call. This is the error message I get:

> The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' header in the response is 'true, true' which must be 'true' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'.

I'm using Spring 4.3.9 and Spring Security 4.2.3.

This is my CORS configuration:

```xml
<bean id="corsConfigurationSource" class="org.springframework.web.cors.UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource">
        <property name="corsConfigurations">
            <map>
                <entry key="/**" value-ref="corsConfig"/>
            </map>
        </property>
</bean>

<bean id="corsConfig" class="org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfiguration">
        <property name="allowedOrigins" value="${settings.cors.origin}"/>
        <property name="allowedHeaders" value="*"/>
        <property name="allowedMethods" value="*"/>
        <property name="allowCredentials" value="true"/>
        <property name="exposedHeaders">
            <list>
                <value>X-Total-Count</value>
                <value>Content-Disposition</value>
            </list>
        </property>
</bean>
```

And this is how I use it in the Spring Security configuration:

```xml
<cors configuration-source-ref="corsConfigurationSource"/>
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem, I had an `authentication-success-handler` (Spring Security) that added this header. I removed it and the problem was solved.